# Scrollreveal.js not working on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, viewport, scrollreveal.js

I tried using scrollreveal.js on `modal`. But i'm having a problem revealing the content when modal is scroll. I've tried changing the viewport(see the code below both not working) to `myModal` but still not working. Thanks for your help. Here my fiddle and code.

```
window.sr = new ScrollReveal({
  viewport: $('#myModal');
});

window.sr = new ScrollReveal({
   viewport: document.getElementById('myModal');
});
```

heres the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nwxLq2zg/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check this fiddle mate https://jsfiddle.net/nwxLq2zg/8/

```
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('.foo', { container: '.modal-body' });
```